# Интеграция reCaptcha в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

Пытаюсь создать кастомную страницу входа на сайт. Установлен модуль Advanced noCaptcha & invisible Captcha, который интегрирует капчу в дефолтную форму входа WP.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo sprintf( "You are logged in <a href='%s'>Log out</a>.", wp_logout_url() );
}else{
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['errno'] ) ) {
        $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['errno'] );

        foreach ( $error_codes as $error_code ) {
            switch ( $error_code ) {
                case 'empty_username':
                    echo '<p class="errno">Empty username.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'empty_password':
                    echo '<p class="errno">Please enter your password.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'invalid_username':
                    echo '<p class="errno">The specified user was not found on the site.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'incorrect_password':
                    echo sprintf( "<p class='errno'>Incorrect password. <a href='%s'>Forgot</a>?</p>", wp_lostpassword_url() );
                    break;
                case 'confirm':
                    echo '<p class="errno success">Instructions are sent to the specified email address.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'changed':
                    echo '<p class="errno success">Password changed.</p>';
                    break;
                case 'expiredkey':
                case 'invalidkey':
                    echo '<p class="errno">Incorrect key.</p>';
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

            wp_login_form(
                array(
                    'redirect' => site_url(),
                )
            );

}
```

Далее в functions.php я прописываю и цепляю к событиям следующие функции:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'redirect_at_authenticate', 101, 3 );

    function redirect_at_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {

        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
            if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
                $error_codes = join( ',', $user->get_error_codes() );

                $login_url = home_url( '/login/' );
                $login_url = add_query_arg( 'errno', $error_codes, $login_url );

                wp_redirect( $login_url );
                exit;
            }
        }

        return $user;


    }

    add_filter("wp_authenticate_user", "check_captcha", 10, 2);

    function check_captcha($user, $password){
        $login_url = home_url( '/login/' );
        $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $data = [
            'secret' => 'here is my secret key',
            'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
        ];
        $options = [
            'http' => [
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => http_build_query($data)
         ]
        ];
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
        if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
          wp_redirect( $login_url );
                exit;
        } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
                    return $user;
        }
    }


    add_action( 'wp_logout', 'logout_redirect', 5 );

    function logout_redirect(){
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/login/?logged_out=true' ) );
        exit;
    }
```

В итоге работает все кроме проверки на капчу, если не ставить галочку в капче, то все отрабатывает и редиректит обратно на эту же страницу, однако если поставить галочку в капче и она показывает что все в порядке,нажимаешь кнопку логина и она показывает что ошибка капчи, причем редиректит на wp-login. Ошибка насколько я понимаю именно в функции check_captcha() у меня, ло нее все работало, кроме варианта когда не отмечаешь галочку в капче. 
Что в моей проверке не так? Или капчу стороннего плагина я так не смогу проверить и надо все писать с нуля, начиная с написания формы и задания ей id и класса капчи?

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, а зачем вот это всё? Плагин вроде работает с формой входа без всякого дополнительного кода.

Comment: Он при этом редиректит на wp-login, стандартную страницу входа, а мне нужна кастомная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос написанием собственной формы и интеграцией капчи напрямую туда. Видимо проблема была в том что плагин сам проверяет корректность заполнения капчи, а я проверял уже повторно и в этот момент капча уже была не заполнена.